# Where is the copyright file applicable to libBLT.2.4.so.8.5 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, copyright-display

Please specify a location in `/usr/share/doc/` if possible.

Comment: Enlighten me. Tell me the grep command you'd use and the directory in which you'd run it, pal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's from the `blt` package. Unless Ubuntu has drifted far from its Debian roots, the copyright file will therefore be at `/usr/share/doc/blt/copyright`. It is also online at http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/b/blt/blt_2.4z-4.2/blt.copyright.

Comment: I don't think so. The BLT I'm interested in has this description, "Libblt is an extension to LibGGI which adds functionality pertaining to blitting and management of blit data sources. LibGGI is a graphics library developed by the GGI Project (http://www.ggi-project.org/)." --http://www.ggi-project.org/docs/libblt-introduction.html

But the project you reference has this description, "The BLT Toolkit is an extension to Tcl and Tk. It adds new commands and widgets to the Tcl interpreter. Included widgets are 2D graph, barchart, stripchart, tab notebook, and tree viewer."

Comment: It's [the only result in the Ubuntu package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libBLT.2.4.so.8.5&mode=filename&suite=maverick&arch=any). If you install a replacement from a third party source, you should specify that in your question.

Comment: I have no idea what source it's from, but I need it. The descriptions also suggest that it isn't a replacement at all. You just guessed based on the shared object name.

Comment: The description linked to by the copyright file doesn't match what I'd guessed the software is being used for, but the copyright file and shared object are both listed in the same file in /var/lib/dpkg/info. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First, use

```
dpkg -S libBLT.2.4.so.8.5
```

to find the package name. Then use

```
dpkg -L <packagename> > /tmp/list
```

to list the files in the package. Then use

```
grep -i copyright `cat /tmp/list`
```

to find all files from the package that mention 'copyright'. One of them will probably be the file you're looking for.